# How to go to user location with Mapkit (Swift)

Tags: swift, mapkit, coordinates, core-location

I am new to app development and I have been trying to create an app which will use core location manager to find the users location and then display it with mapkit. Below is the code I came up with. I haven't been able to fix it, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MapKit Test
//
//  Created by TMT on 7/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 TMT Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    mapView.delegate = self

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

  // For use in foreground
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
     locationManager.delegate = self
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
     locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }

  @NSCopying var location: CLLocation! { get }


  var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2
     , 0.2)

  var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

  mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


  var request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
  request.naturalLanguageQuery = "library"


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Check out this sample https://github.com/talhaqamar/Map-demo-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the delegate method for the location/map.  Your code is setting up the map and location frameworks and delegate methods.  You have initialized them and told the compiler you want to do something with mapkit/corelocation.  So now you need to to handle the delegate methods `MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate` which you have included, and set to `self`

Place the delegate handling in addition to your code somewhere

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    //Get map location
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //Get co ordinates
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            println("Error with the data.")
        }
    })
}
func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {

//Remove observer
self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

println(placemark.locality)
println(placemark.postalCode)
println(placemark.administrativeArea)
println(placemark.country)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to put this? I tried pasting it into my code and I just got a pile of errors.